# Rename file name by removing given prefix pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the following files in txt format:

[image]

**Expected File Format**: I want to remove prefix from file name that is `1. a1.` and while renaming if the file already present with same name then append `_1`, `_2` to the file as given below in example.

[image]

**My try**:

```
import os
import re
import shutil
import argparse

pattern = "a1" 
path = "/Users/a1/Documents/Files" 

count = 0

p = ".* "+str(pattern)+".(.+)"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

for file in files: 
        
        m = re.match(p, file)

        if m is not None:
            
            file_new = m.group(1)
    
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(root,file_new)):
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root,file_new))
            else:
                count = count + 1
                file_new = m.group(1)+"_"+str(count)
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root,file_new))
```

And this is what the output I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What specifically does your code do wrong? Have you done any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: You're using a single counter for all filenames, not starting over at 1 for each filename. You should use a loop in the `else:` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dict` for saving the count of repeating each `file_name` and use saving count in `Dict` for renaming.

```
import os
import re

pattern = "a1" 
path = "Files/" 

dct = {}                                                      # <- adding this
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files: 
            if pattern in file:
                file_new = file.split(pattern, 1)[1]
                if not file_new in dct:                        # <- adding this
                    os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), 
                              os.path.join(root,file_new[1:]))
                    dct[file_new] = 1                          # <- adding this
                else:
                    num = dct[file_new]                        # <- adding this
                    dct[file_new] += 1                         # <- adding this
                    file_name, file_type = file_new[1:].split('.')
                    os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), 
                              os.path.join(root, f'{file_name}_{num}.{file_type}'))
```

Filename before renaming:

[image]

Filename after renaming:

[image]

Comment: If I ran same script couple of times on same path it's giving me error `Cannot create a file when that file already exists`, this was not the case with my script.

Comment: I run multiple and don't get any errors, what are your filenames? do you have multiple patterns?

Comment: Some file's are already in format like `F1` and we have `1. a1.F1` also, in this case if I ran the script it got failed.

Comment: Because In the first run, we remove `a1` in the second run this code doesn't find any match in filenames. can You send all filenames that you got an error? I check this sample that you send

Comment: I also have files like `3. a1.File3.a1_`,`7. a1.File2.a1`,`10. a1.File4_a1.File`. Which should be `File3.a1_`,`File2.a1`, `File4_a1.File`

Comment: @MAK, instead of this line : `file.split(pattern)[1]` try this : `file_new = file.split(pattern, 1)[1]` and this work for new filename